# Store multiple checkbox values in one localStorage key

Tags: javascript, checkbox, local-storage

How can I store multiple checkbox classnames in localStorage (when checked).
The below script stores only one value, value:test in key:filter

It needs to store values: ["test2","test3"] when having these checkboxes checked. Maybe by using data-filter? I also would like to store the classname of the checkbox.

What I have:

```
$(function () {
    var data = localStorage.getItem("filter");
    if (data !== null) {
        $("input[name='filter']").attr("checked", "checked");
    }
});

$("input[name='filter']").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        localStorage.setItem("filter", "test");
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem("filter");
    } 
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="filterbox">
  <label><input name="filter" type="checkbox" class="test1" data-filter="1" /> Test 1 </label>
  <label><input name="filter" type="checkbox" class="test2" data-filter="2" /> Test 2 </label>
  <label><input name="filter" type="checkbox" class="test3" data-filter="3" /> Test 3 </label>
  <label><input name="filter" type="checkbox" class="test4" data-filter="4" /> Test 4 </label>
</div>
```

A fiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/Dp4Tj/264/

Comment: well.. if it is needed you can store string. do you want to know how to create string from array?

Comment: Have a look at `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

Comment: Just posted an answer using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j6ukqnrv/11/

You can accomplish this by passing an array and using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse when you are reading from and writing to local storage.

The Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var data = localStorage.getItem("filter");
    if (data !== null) {
        $("input[name='filter']").attr("checked", "checked");
    }
});

$("input[name='filter']").click(function (event) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var filterid = event.target.getAttribute('data-filter');
        var storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('filter'));
        var arr = [];
        if(storage) {
          arr = storage;
            arr.push(filterid);
        } else {
            arr.push(filterid);
        }

        console.log(arr)
        localStorage.setItem("filter", JSON.stringify(arr));
    } else {
        var filterid = event.target.getAttribute('data-filter');
        var storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('filter'));
        var arr = [];
        if(storage) {
            arr = storage;
            var index = arr.indexOf(filterid);
            if (index > -1) {
                arr.splice(index, 1);
            }
            localStorage.setItem("filter", JSON.stringify(arr));
        }
    } 
});
```

your HTML:

```
<div class="filterbox">
  <label><input name="filter" type="checkbox" class="test1" data-filter="1" /> Test 1 </label>
  <label><input name="filter" type="checkbox" class="test2" data-filter="2" /> Test 2 </label>
  <label><input name="filter" type="checkbox" class="test3" data-filter="3" /> Test 3 </label>
  <label><input name="filter" type="checkbox" class="test4" data-filter="4" /> Test 4 </label>
</div>
```

[image: Fiddle local storage screenshot]

Comment: Hi Dylan, does it work with you? I don't see anything stored in LocalStorage when clicking on a checkbox.

Comment: It does. In the context of the fiddle, make sure you are looking at fiddle.jshell.net. I just added an image.

Comment: Seems in Chrome it works indeed. I use Firefox and it doesn't seem to store anything.

Comment: You are right. I needed to pass event as a parameter to get the clicked element's attributes. I updated that in the new fiddle link and the code: http://jsfiddle.net/j6ukqnrv/11/

Comment: Yes it now does work! Thank you very much, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
$(function () {
var data = localStorage.getItem("filter").split(',');
console.log(data)
$.each(data, function (i, v) {
    $("input[class='" + v + "']").prop('checked', true);
});


$("input[name='filter']").change(function () {
    var selected = [];
    $("input[name='filter']:checked").each(function () {
        selected.push($(this).attr('class'));
    });
    console.log(selected);
    localStorage.setItem("filter", selected.toString());
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) since you need to pass strings to [localStorage.setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem):

```js
var arr = ["test2", "test3"];
localStorage.setItem("filter", JSON.stringify(arr));
var newArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("filter"));
console.log(newArray); // ["test2", "test3"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I see the values are indeed test2 and 3. But how can I make it working for my example. Sorry for not understanding how to do that.